# Hi I am using jvectormap and I am looking for a way to detect the current zoomstep. Anyone an idea?

Tags: maps, jvectormap

Hi I am using jvectormap and I am  looking for a way to get the current zoomstep (after a pinch/zoom). Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

if you use the version 1.2.2 you can listen the event onViewportChange, this event receive two params (event,number), the number is the zoom level.

if you use the version 1.1.1 you need make changes in the js check my changes:http://pastebin.com/s5GwcEMy

i add the onViewportChange event to the api.

Other way is get the map reference:

```
map = $("#world-map-gdp").vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

and get the scale:

```
var scale = map.scale;
```